# Batch File Gives Message: "1 was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, webserver

I wrote a batch file that checks if a server is online. It uses a few cygwin-64 tools.

Here's the batch file:

```
wget -S http://www.example.com/ -o headers.txt -O index.html
cat http-commands.txt | ncat --idle-timeout 5 -vvv www.example.com 80 >> ncat.txt

unix2dos headers.txt

grep -i apache headers.txt > comparison-now.txt

fc comparison-known-good.txt comparison-now.txt

if %errorlevel% 1 goto email

echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%

if %errorlevel% 0 goto good

:email
del /f /q files.zip
zip -xi ncat.txt index.html headers.txt files.zip
C:\commands\Blat.exe C:\path\message.txt -attach C:\path\files.zip -tf     C:\path\recipients.txt -subject "Example.com Down!" -server relay.server.com -f example@gmail.com -log C:\path\log.txt -debug -timestamp -overwritelog 


:good
REM Hooray! The server is alive!
exit
```

The output is below:

```
1 was unexpected at this time.
C:\path>if 0 1 goto email
```

Perhaps the logic should be this, since there's only going to be two different errors?

```
if errorlevel 1 do this
.
else do this
```

Comment: The simplest solution to your code would have just been to remove the percent symbols from the errorlevel variable. `if errorlevel 1 goto email` and `if errorlevel 0 goto good`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Batch File Gives Message: "1 was unexpected at this time"

You are using:

```
if %errorlevel% 1 goto email
```

...

```
if %errorlevel% 0 goto good
```

Try instead:

```
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto email
```

...

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto good
```

---

#### IF - Conditionally perform a command

> IF will only parse numbers when one of (EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ)
>   is used. The == comparison operator always results in a string
>   comparison.
>
> IF ERRORLEVEL n statements should be read as IF Errorlevel >= number
>
> IF ERRORLEVEL 0 will return TRUE when the errorlevel is 64
>
> An alternative and often better method of checking Errorlevels is to
>   use the %ERRORLEVEL% variable:
>
> ```
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 Echo An error was found
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 0 Echo An error was found
>
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 Echo No error found
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (Echo No error found) ELSE (Echo An error was found)
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 Echo No error found || Echo An error was found
> ```

Source [IF - Conditionally perform a command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.